# MySQL: fetch multiple global status and system variable in a single query

Tags: performance, mysql-5.1, query-performance

When we execute `SHOW global status;` or `SHOW variables;` we get list of 291 and 278 records in the resultset. For performance perspective, only few of them are much important. I have to fetch these variables many times during performance hit. 
For example, can we write below multiple statement into one?

```
show global status like 'Threads_cached';
show global status like 'Threads_connected';
show global status like 'Threads_created';
show global status like 'Threads_running';
show global status like 'Select_scan';
```

If we fetch these variables in a single statement, it will be really a great help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS where VARIABLE_NAME like 'Threads_cached' or VARIABLE_NAME like 'Threads_connected' or VARIABLE_NAME like 'Threads_created' or VARIABLE_NAME like 'Threads_running' or VARIABLE_NAME like 'Select_scan';
```

Comment: thanks. In this way, we can find all the specific variables.

Comment: @Kazimieras Aliulis,
 How to add Com_commit + Com_rollback to find out TPS for performance ? I believe TPS => (Com_Commit + Com_rollback ) / second gives out the TPS. Could you give a query to calculate out TPS , Please guide me.

Comment: This may need an update. The `global_status` in recent MySQL versions (eg. 8.0, 5.7) is in the `performance_schema` schema, and it also doesn't include `Com_` values.

Comment: I get "Error Code: 3167. The 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS' feature is disabled; (...)"  :(

Answer (score 2):

Remember that in MySQL 8 the global_status table has been moved to the performance_schema, therefore you should query:

```
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.global_status
 WHERE VARIABLE_NAME like 'Open_files'
    OR VARIABLE_NAME like 'Uptime';
```

Answer (score 1):

If we assume the usage of the `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` (therefore, exclude the performance schema), don't forget that the statement supports `WHERE` conditions, which fit nicely with the regexp match operator (`RLIKE`):

```sql
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS WHERE Variable_name RLIKE '^(Threads_cached|Threads_connected|Threads_created|Threads_running|Select_scan)$'
```